# Groovyc NoSuchMethodException

Tags: ant, groovy

I'm using Groovyc to compile a project in Ant. That's how i'm doing :

```
<path id="lib.path">
    <fileset dir="${pathWhereIsTheJar&Others}">
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path> 

<taskdef name="groovyc" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc" classpathref="lib.path"/>
```

The thing is: Everytime i run the task i get the following Exception:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.createCompilationOptions()Lgroovyjarjarcommonscli/Options;

I'm using the groovy-all-2.1.3.jar and according to [grepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/2.1.3/org/codehaus/groovy/tools/FileSystemCompiler.java#FileSystemCompiler.createCompilationOptions%28%29) this method exists on this version.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Ant. Edited there. Thanks ;)

Comment: Full stack trace might help.